# RPI-4 Bluetooth board does not find iOS devices

Tags: python, pi-4, bluetooth, raspberry-pi-os, ios

On a brand new RPI-4, I cannot find apple iphones neither using module bluetooth nor bluez package.

I tried to scan for BLE devices and all the command line tools such as bluetoothctl and hciconfig to scan for devices or to reset bluetooth controller but without success in both cases.

I also bought another rpi 4 and got same results with different iOS devices while I can connect and work with many android devices.
Anyone is having the same issue?

busctl monitor org.bluez = gives no output

btmon gives this output:

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.50
= Note: Linux version 5.10.11-v7l+ (armv7l)                                          0.618922
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                             0.618929
= New Index: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15 (Primary,USB,hci0)                             [hci0] 0.618933
= Open Index: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15                                               [hci0] 0.618935
= Index Info: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15 (Cambridge Silicon Radio)                     [hci0] 0.618938
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.18                           {0x0001} 0.618942
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.18                                {0x0002} 0.619015
```

journalctl -f -u bluetooth gives this output:

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2021-04-28 16:25:02 CEST. --
Apr 28 16:25:05 cloudiosmarthome systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Apr 28 16:25:05 cloudiosmarthome bluetoothd[362]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Apr 28 16:25:06 cloudiosmarthome bluetoothd[362]: Starting SDP server
Apr 28 16:25:06 cloudiosmarthome systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 28 16:25:06 cloudiosmarthome bluetoothd[362]: Bluetooth management interface 1.18 initialized
Apr 28 16:25:06 cloudiosmarthome bluetoothd[362]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Apr 28 16:25:06 cloudiosmarthome bluetoothd[362]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

while bluetoothctl scan on command found everything except for iOS devices:

```
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 55:D6:E7:C5:EB:16 55-D6-E7-C5-EB-16
[NEW] Device EC:55:F9:CA:45:47 VAIO-MINI
[CHG] Device EC:55:F9:CA:45:47 RSSI: -52
[CHG] Device 55:D6:E7:C5:EB:16 RSSI: -78
[NEW] Device 68:43:4F:50:F7:7F 68-43-4F-50-F7-7F
[NEW] Device E4:84:86:D1:A1:E4 SumUp 958
[CHG] Device E4:84:86:D1:A1:E4 RSSI: -77
[CHG] Device 55:D6:E7:C5:EB:16 RSSI: -70
[CHG] Device 55:D6:E7:C5:EB:16 RSSI: -82
[CHG] Device 55:D6:E7:C5:EB:16 RSSI: -72
```

maybe I should use ibeacon approach?
https://learn.adafruit.com/pibeacon-ibeacon-with-a-raspberry-pi/what-is-ibeacon

Comment: Your question is very broad at the moment. Are the iOS devices advertising? When running your scans have separate terminals open with the following running to get more debug information: `bluetootctl`, `journalctl -f -u bluetooth`, `sudo busctl monitor org.bluez`, `sudo btmon`

Comment: question updated with your suggestions

Comment: There is nothing in your updates that gives any clues. Could it be the privacy setting on iOS or on the RPi?
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt#n1846

Comment: The `mgmt` API for BlueZ can be access from the command line with `sudo btmgmt` and then type `help` to see the commnds.